# Is there a case statement in Haml-Coffee?

Tags: coffeescript, haml

I'd like to do the following in Haml-Coffee:

```
- case msg.type
- when "usertext"
    = msg.body          
- when "direct"
    = msg.content.kbcontent_body
```

But I get an error "Reserved word "case""

I suspect it's not supported by Haml-Coffee actually.

Comment: Why is the rails tag on here if it's for coffeescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a `case` statement in CoffeeScript. You want `switch` — the `case` keyword is the JavaScript equivalent of `when`, and like many dropped JavaScript keywords is reserved in CoffeeScript. Also, I'm not 100% positive and don't have Haml-Coffee to test right now, but I *think* you'll need to indent the body of the switch.

Answer (score 27):

Before the question was edited, it's main phrase had been:

### Is there a case statement in HAML?

The answer is: in vanilla Haml [there indeed is `case`!](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_blocks)

```
%p
  - case 2
  - when 1
    = "1!"
  - when 2
    = "2?"
  - when 3
    = "3."
```

Comment: Well, this is true of mainline Haml, but it isn't true of Haml Coffee, which is what the question was about.

Comment: The question was: "Is there a case statement in HAML?". There is.

Comment: The question specifically says "it's HAML-Coffee". You can go test it in Haml Coffee if you want to see for yourself — this code will not work. And BTW, revenge-downvoting is not classy and encourages silent downvotes, which isn't a good outcome.

Comment: Yeah but they put the ruby-on-rails tag on it totally confusing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any complex ruby code in haml using `:ruby` syntax when it is extremely necessary. Keep this on top level and use the resulting variable in your coffee haml

```
:ruby
  x = case a
  when 2
     "two"
  when 3
     "three"
  end
```